# SharePoint 2010: Setting Up Incoming Email

Tags: 2010, incoming-email, exchange-server

I need a starting point for figuring out how to set up an incoming email "help@hospitalname.org" for my hospital. I am in hospital IT, but I do not know where to begin with this task.

Can someone please provide me with resources to begin wrapping my head around how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit too long to post here, but I wrote [A Practical Guide to Implementing Incoming Email using the SharePoint Directory Management Service](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/02/a-practical-guide-to-implementing-incoming-email-using-the-sharepoint-directory-management-service/) which walks through the entire process.

Microsoft also has the official article, [Configure incoming e-mail (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947(v=office.14).aspx); again, this is too long to post here.